# Running a program with autologin not working like running on bash

Tags: linux, ceph

I wrote a program and its automatically installs ceph.
This program works fine when I run manually But when I login automatically with getty (my conf below) and run the program as last line in /etc/profile "like this "./myapp", I get the following authorization errors.

```
** ERROR: error creating empty object store in /var/lib/ceph/tmp/mnt.XSlAG1: (13) Permission denied
```

The problem occurs when the program runs `ceph-disk activate`

What is my problem?

```
/etc/systemd/system/getty\@tty1.service.d/autologin.conf
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=-/usr/bin/agetty --skip-login --login-options "-f root" %I 38400 linux
```

Comment: It works when you login via getty and run it manually? Or is that a different kind of login? You should run `ceph-disk activate` through `strace` in order to see which access fails: `strace -o ceph.strace -f ceph-disk activate`

Comment: Works when I login as root via getty. Autologin ruins it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`man 1 login` says:

> -f
>   Used to skip a second login authentication.  This specifically does not work for root, and does not appear to work well under Linux.

You are doing `--login-options "-f root"` which is explicitly not supposed to work.

So I assume what is supposed to be a root shell is not a root shell. You may add `whoami` to /etc/profile to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Running with sudo solved my problem. "/usr/bin/sudo /root/myapp"
I'm root when I autologin but something different which I still don't know.

What ever my problem solved. Thank you guys.